# cordova-plugin-media return error failed to start recording using avaudiorecorder code 1 on ios

Tags: javascript, cordova

try to record voice using cordova media plugin on ios but always return error failed to start recording using avaudiorecorder ,code 1

> ```
>                    var src = "myrecording.m4a";
>                     
>                         mediaRec = new Media(src, function () {
>                             alert("Success");
>                         }, function (err) {
>                             alert(JSON.stringify(err));
>                         });
>                     
>                     mediaRec.startRecord();
>
>                     alert("Recording Started");
>                     console.log(mediaRec);
> ```

Comment: please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: code edited  now